# Is it possible to send mails periodically from iOS app

Tags: ios, email

I'm developing an app that creates a simple document with basic information created by the app. It won't contain any personal information, but it will contain data created and requested by the user. I want the user to be able to send this to themselves via email. I would also like to add the option for the user to have this file (which updates daily) to be able to send to them automatically every week/month, so they won't have to think about it. The user can set the intervals themselves.

Is this possible? The user will set up this option themselves from a menu, so it's not like they won't know it's happening. Every automatic mail will also contain information on how to turn the option back off again.

Is this possible and is it allowed by Apple?

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible from within the app. A user has to explicitly send the email through the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

If you want this functionality, you should build a backend for your app.

To clarify, if you want to use the users configured accounts; i.e. the account they use with Mail, then no you cannot do this automatically. The other answers rely on the fact a user enters their POP/IMAP settings, which personally I would never do.

Comment: That's not true. It involves doing some lower level stuff, but you can send email in the background

Comment: I can't imagine the Apple review team being too happy about that, but if it works for you then great.

Comment: Sometimes you have to tread the dangerous waters of the Apple review guidelines if you want to do things a bit differently

Answer (score 0):

You could use an email service as mandril or mailgun, to send emails "from your app".

Take a look at this: https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called `MailCore` that's incredibly powerful. You can use it to send mail in the background of your app without needing to present the built in mail composer view

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2

Comment: will these get through the review? did you try/use it before in a production app?

Comment: @nburk I've only used it in an enterprise app, but I've looked into the guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). There is not a single mention of not being allowed to send email without their interface. Think about it. There are email clients in the App Store, Gmail being a popular example. Those clients are doing the same low level stuff to use SMTP and IMAP. That's all MailCore is, a mail client